# Desktop file isn't running

Tags: command-line, .desktop

So I've tested and my sh file runs just fine. But meanwhile, these desktop files never run correctly. I have tried running the same command and checking it in terminal to make sure that my path is correct. Running `./home/padded-gamer/Downloads/Twine.sh` runs just fine and boots up Twine easily.

It doesn't appear to be my fault in any regard. I've troubleshooted and gotten the command to run through terminal. But not through desktop. I have physically googled every possible method on the Internet. So I have no idea.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Twine
Version=2.2.1
Type=Application 
Terminal=False
Exec=/home/padded-gamer/Downloads/Twine.sh
```

The sh file looks like this and runs perfectly.

```
 #!/bin/bash
./Downloads/twine_2.2.1/Twine
```

Comment: Why not launch the game directly instead of using a Bash script that does nothing but launch the game? PS: Bash may require a terminal or a different type.

Comment: `Twine.sh` looks for the executable *from its own directory* (using `./`). You need to cd into that dir first: `Exec=/bin/bash -c "cd <directory> && run...."` Nicely documented question +1.